# Why doesn't my ACR38 SmartCard Reader work?

Tags: hardware

I've this SmartCard reader:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 072f:90cc Advanced Card Systems, Ltd ACR38 SmartCard Reader
```

I've installed the following packages: **pcscd**, **libacr38u**, **pcsc-tools**, and a driver available on this website http://www.bit4id.com/italiano/download/download_file/Linux.zip

the **pcscd** daemon seems running:

```
andrea@centurion:~$ ps -e | grep pcsc
 2799 ?        00:00:00 pcscd
```

when I try to test if the smart card is working, I get no reply:

```
andrea@centurion:~$ pcsc_scan 
PC/SC device scanner
V 1.4.16 (c) 2001-2009, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>
Compiled with PC/SC lite version: 1.5.3
Scanning present readers...
Waiting for the first reader...
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using the 64-bit version of Ubuntu, and which version are you using (9.10, 10.04, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your ACR38 is supported by the CCID driver libccid

http://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/ccid/supported.html#0x072F0x90CC

Answer (score 2):

## How to get the eid electronic card reader ACR38U working in Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit

Prerequisites: Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit, newest version of Mozilla Firefox, pcscd, default-jre, opensc, libacr38u,  libacr38ucontrol0, libacsccid1, libccid

In a Terminal session, run the following commands:

`sudo aptitude update`

`sudo aptitude install firefox pcscd  default-jre  opensc libacr38u libacr38ucontrol0 libacsccid1  libccid`

`sudo aptitude remove --purge beid*`

`wget http://eid.belgium.be/fr/binaries/eid-mw_4%2E0%2E4r1253_amd64_tcm226-178472.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i eid-mw_4.0.4r1253_amd64_tcm226-178472.deb`

`wget http://eid.belgium.be/fr/binaries/eid-viewer_4%2E0%2E4r146_amd64_tcm226-178482.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i eid-viewer_4.0.4r146_amd64_tcm226-178482.deb`

Manually set the following values in Mozilla Firefox in about:config

security.ssl.allow_unrestricted_renego_everywhere__temporarily_available_pref;true
security.ssl.enable_false_start;true
security.ssl.renego_unrestricted_hosts;*.be

Manually replace the security.ssl.renego_unrestricted_hosts name
 certif.belgium.be or *.be in about:config,  if you want to authenticate on a DIFFERENT site than www.cm.be or test.eid.belgium.be !!!

Download Belgium Root certificates here:

http://repository.eid.belgium.be/certificates.php?cert=Root&lang=en

Import Belgium Root certificates into Firefox.

The Belgium Root certificates are required if you want to use the applications of the FSP Finance (Belcotax, Intervat, Finprof, etc.).

Before you begin, make sure your identity card is in the card reader. Then:

```
Viewing certificates
    For Linux: Go to Edit > Preferences > Advanced > Encryption and click ‘View certificates’.
Check-marking certificates

Follow the steps below for the ‘Belgium Root CA’ and ‘Belgium Root CA2’ certificates. Can you only find one certificate? Then you obviously only have to perform these steps once.
    Find the ‘Belgium Root CA’ or ‘Belgium Root CA2’ certificate and click the line below the arrow.
    Click ‘Edit…’.
    Check ALL three boxes.
    Click ‘OK’.
```

Ensure that there are absolutely NO add-ons or plugins installed in Mozilla Firefox.
Installing the Belgium eid Firefox add-on will NOT work in Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit and only make matters worse!

Disconnect the eid card reader from the PC.
Reconnect the eid card reader from the PC.

Insert eid card into card reader.

Reboot the PC.

Test eid card reader here:

http://test.eid.belgium.be/

Comment: still useful & working in 2018

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04, I just installed the driver here https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/199/acr38u-i1-smart-card-reader/  following the internal readme.txt in the zip file and it worked

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming here for Ubuntu 18.04, I did the following to get it working :

```
sudo apt-get install libpcsclite1
```

Download and install the ACR38 driver manually from https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/199/acr38u-i1-smart-card-reader/

Unzip the downloaded driver and open a terminal in that directory + install the debian package

```
cd ubuntu/artful
```

(it is for Ubuntu 17.10 but working. MAybe there will be a 18.04 directory in the future...)

```
sudo dpkg -i libacsccid1_1.1.5-1~ubuntu17.10.1_amd64.deb
```

Restart pcsc daemon

```
sudo service pcscd restart
```

and the reaer was recognized (with pcsc_scan at least, and later with Belgian EID program)

Comment: thank you, I had to install `pcscd` and `pcsc-tools` on my Ubuntu flavor to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Ubuntu 10.04 or later, then judging by the [bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=433129) [reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acr38/+bug/331283) you shouldn't be experiencing this issue anymore. (Version 1.7.10 of `libacr38u`).

Seeing as the driver you downloaded is two years old, and there is a package to provide support for this device in the Ubuntu respositories (`libacr38u`) then I would keep away from the driver.

If you are on Ubuntu 10.04 or later (especially if it doesn't work in 10.10) then please [report a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug/5126#5126) by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `ubuntu-bug libacr38u`.

Comment: I have the same card reader but not working. When i use this tool it does not detect the card information but only `pcsc_scan` shows information. How can i work on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit with this card reader?

Comment: Basically this eid-viewer works for many card reader but this one is not working. http://eid.belgium.be/en/using_your_eid/installing_the_eid_software/linux/